# How to display popup with longitudes and latatitude on multiple rectangles in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using Google API maps for drawing multiple rectangles on the Map, trying to find a way where I can display a popup of dataset on hover of all the rectangles. This popup will display the latitudes and longitudes of multiple rectangles.

Visit https://codepen.io/thephpjo/pen/XKjqxB!
Above mentioned code is the one i am using.

Here is my code
`
// This example adds a red rectangle to a map.

```
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: {lat: 51.5, lng: 15},
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });
    
    var countries = [
      {
        color: '#FF0000',
        minLat: 47.27,
        maxLat: 55.05,
        minLong: 5.87,
        maxLong: 15.03
      },{
        color: '#00FF00',
        minLat: 45.82,
        maxLat: 47.8,
        minLong: 5.97,
        maxLong: 10.49
      },{
        color: '#0000FF',
        minLat: 46.38,
        maxLat: 49.02,
        minLong: 9.54,
        maxLong: 17.16
      },{
        color: '#00FFFF',
        minLat: 48.56,
        maxLat: 51.03,
        minLong: 12.1,
        maxLong: 18.86
      },{
        color: '#FFFF00',
        minLat: 41.19,
        maxLat: 81.86,
        minLong: 27.9,
        maxLong: 170
      }
    ];

    countries.forEach(function(c) {
      new google.maps.Rectangle({
      strokeColor: c.color,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: c.color,
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      bounds: {
        north: c.minLat,
        south: c.maxLat,
        east:  c.maxLong,
        west:  c.minLong
      }
    });
    });
   
  }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"This popup will display the latitudes and longitudes of multiple rectangles."` - if this means that you wish to use a single infowindow to display data for multiple polygons individually rather than all at once then perhaps the following will be of interest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rectangles</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script>

      // This example adds a red rectangle to a map.
     function initMap() {
        let overlays=[];
        
        let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        
        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 51.5, lng: 15},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });
        
        const countries = [
          {
            title:'Polygon A',
            color: '#FF0000',
            minLat: 47.27,
            maxLat: 55.05,
            minLong: 5.87,
            maxLong: 15.03
          },{
            title:'Polygon B',
            color: '#00FF00',
            minLat: 45.82,
            maxLat: 47.8,
            minLong: 5.97,
            maxLong: 10.49
          },{
            title:'Polygon C',
            color: '#0000FF',
            minLat: 46.38,
            maxLat: 49.02,
            minLong: 9.54,
            maxLong: 17.16
          },{
            title:'Polygon D',
            color: '#00FFFF',
            minLat: 48.56,
            maxLat: 51.03,
            minLong: 12.1,
            maxLong: 18.86
          },{
            title:'Polygon E',
            color: '#FFFF00',
            minLat: 41.19,
            maxLat: 81.86,
            minLong: 27.9,
            maxLong: 170
          }
        ];
        
        // Find the LatLngBounds for the Polygon
        google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds=function(){
            let b = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            this.getPath().forEach(o=>b.extend(o));
            return b;
        };
        
        // function to add new Polygon and assign it's event listeners
        const oRectangle=(o)=>{
            
            // assign properties from countries object
            let rectangle=new google.maps.Rectangle({
                title:o.title,
                strokeColor:o.color,
                strokeOpacity:0.8,
                strokeWeight:2,
                fillColor:o.color,
                fillOpacity:0.35,
                map:map,
                bounds: {
                    north:o.minLat,
                    south:o.maxLat,
                    east:o.maxLong,
                    west:o.minLong
                }
            });
            
            // popup the infowindow when user hovers over polygon
            rectangle.addListener('mouseover',function(e){
                let bounds=this.getBounds();
                // calculate the cardinal points for the bounds
                // use ne & sw to calculate nw & se
                let ne=bounds.getNorthEast();
                let sw=bounds.getSouthWest();
                let nw=new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(),sw.lng());
                let se=new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(),ne.lng());
                
                // create whatever content you wish to display
                let content=`
                <div>
                    <h1>${this.title}</h1>
                    <div>Northeast: ${ne.lat()}, ${ne.lng()}</div>
                    <div>Northwest: ${nw.lat()}, ${nw.lng()}</div>
                    <div>Southeast: ${se.lat()}, ${se.lng()}</div>
                    <div>Southwest: ${sw.lat()}, ${sw.lng()}</div>
                </div>`;
                infowindow.setContent( content );
                infowindow.setPosition( e.latLng )
                infowindow.setMap( map );
            });
            
            rectangle.addListener('mouseout',function(e){
                infowindow.close();
            });
            
            rectangle.addListener('mousemove',function(e){
                infowindow.setPosition( e.latLng )
            });

            return rectangle;
        }
        
        // add the overlays / polygons
        countries.forEach( country =>{
            overlays.push( oRectangle.call( this, country ) );
        })
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyBq.................."></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/6uyjLn5z/1/)

The above produces the following

[image: example maps display]

Comment: Thankyou so much Professor! This was indeed a great and a fast response!